# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, even when i have checked that the parameter 2 is an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

> I have retrieved data from WordPress database with a loop. The query
>   is as below.

```
$family_tot = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_family` WHERE `id` = '".$family_list_total[$k] -> id."%' ORDER BY `wp_family`.`family_name` ASC LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page", OBJECT );
```

> Here `$product_cookingIDs = $family_list_total[$k]->food_complements;`
>   returns four serialized arrays as listed below.

```
N;
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"78";i:1;s:2:"80";}
N;
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"79";i:1;s:2:"80";}
```

> Now I have converting these serialized arrays to simple arrays usimg the code given below. And also checking if these are arrays or not.

```
$product_cookingIDs_total = unserialize($product_cookingIDs);
if(is_array($product_cookingIDs_total)){
    print_r($product_cookingIDs_total);
    echo " Is an array <br>";
}
else{
    echo $product_cookingIDs;
    echo " Is not an array <br>";
}
```

> And the above code returns this,

```
N; Is not an array
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 80 ) Is an array
N; Is not an array
Array ( [0] => 79 [1] => 80 ) Is an array
```

> Now I have changed the above code to the code given below,

```
if($product_cookingIDs != "N;"){
    $product_cookingIDs_total = unserialize($product_cookingIDs);
    print_r($product_cookingIDs_total);
}
```

> And it returns two arrays as listed below,

```
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 80 )
Array ( [0] => 79 [1] => 80 )
```

> But when i am trying to check in_array for these results with the code given below,

```
if(in_array($familydata_id, $product_cookingIDs_total) ){
    print_r($product_cookingIDs_total);
    echo "yes";         
}
```

> It returns **Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array** with the same line number in the code.

Comment: it returns "is not an array" for the string "N;" , but I am checking for the two arrays and even for them it returns the **Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array**. @Jon

Comment: Yes it will return this warning for first and 3rd record as these values are string `N; & N;`

Comment: But it returns the same even i am excluding those string using this code.
`if($product_cookingIDs != "N;"){
    $product_cookingIDs_total = unserialize($product_cookingIDs);
    print_r($product_cookingIDs_total);
}`

@itzmukeshy7

Comment: How you are excluding `N; & N;`?

Comment: I have excluded `N; & N;` using the code given in the previous comment. @itzmukeshy7

Comment: And outside this `if` condition you are again looping the result set and using `in_array()` on the all 4 records right? So share all code as it it you are trying;

Comment: No I am using the new variable that i defined in this condition, `$product_cookingIDs_total = unserialize($product_cookingIDs);'`@itzmukeshy7

Comment: try `$product_cookingIDs_total = (array) unserialize($product_cookingIDs);` so you always have an array, even empty one if `unserialize()` does not return one

Comment: Yes, that's right. this one also worked for me. @drndavi thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this code

```
if($product_cookingIDs != "N;"){
    $product_cookingIDs_total = unserialize($product_cookingIDs);
    if(in_array($familydata_id,$product_cookingIDs_total) ){
        print_r($product_cookingIDs_total);
        echo "yes";
        $cooking = $wpdb -> get_row("SELECT * FROM `wp_woocommerce_custom_field` WHERE id=".$familydata_id);
        $product_list_cooking[] = array($product_list[$i] -> ID,$product->get_image('full'),$product -> get_title(),$cooking -> name,$color_class);                 
        }
    }
```